# bash script - rename all files in a directory containing *space *() *-

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, sh

I'm running out of options here..

I had a look at various posts here about the subject, yet for some reason the answers did not work for me.

I want a simple script to rename all files in a given folder to anything! say a counter nr. i.e.:

> 1.jpg
>
> 2.pdf
>
> 3.exe

I need this for part of my script as I cannot move the files as these have special characters:

I'm using **cygwin** on a **win7** machine, the files are created from **win7** i.e.:

```
test01.jpg
test01 (2).jpg
test01 (2) - Copy.jpg
```

This is the part of the script which I need to make it work:

```
pathF="d:/scripts/img/_sandbox/depFrom"
searchAll=$(find $pathF -type f | egrep ".*")
ct=0
for fAll in $searchAll; do
    # echo -e $fAll
    # echo -e "$ct"
    old=$fAll
    # new=$(sed "s/\ //g" $fAll)
    mv -v $old $ct #$new
    ((ct++))
done
```

In this example I only wanted to deal with **spaces**, but I need to deal with () - and spaces to cover all.

This is the output in my console:
[image: output]
For some reason it seems to stop/split at the space in between and after the extension.

Any help is much appreciated.

==================================================================

**EDIT:**
I have tried this:

```
pathF="d:/scripts/img/_sandbox/depFrom"
searchAll=$(find $pathF -type f -printf "%f\n")
for fAll in $searchAll; do
    echo -e $fAll
done
```

And the output is this:

```
test01
(2)
-
Copy.jpg
```

There is only one file in the folder!!

```
$ ls depFrom/
test01 (2) - Copy.jpg

$ find depFrom/ -type f -printf "%f\n"
test01 (2) - Copy.jpg
```

Comment: `x=0;for i in *.jpg;do mv "$i" $((++x)).jpg;done` ?

Comment: I have the same result, this would only increase the name of the file. The issue seems to be in reading the files..

Comment: There are so many race conditions you haven't even considered, that make a reliable solution almost impossible. But why don't you ask for the [short file name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#short_vs._long_names) instead? It's guaranteed to not contain any spaces.

Comment: I have no idea what you want, there is no difficulty reading the filename using what i posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work so long as the file names don't contain newlines.

```
pathF="d:/scripts/img/_sandbox/depFrom"
counter=0
find "$pathF" -type f | while read f; do
    mv "$f" "$((++counter))${f/*\./.}" #increment counter, preserve extension
done
```

If you don't need a recursive search of pathF, then the solution presented in 123's comment under your original question should work for you, if you add the extension preserving code from my answer:

```
x=0;for i in *;do mv "$i" "$((++x))${i/*\./.}";done
```

Comment: This seemed to have worked, I think the bit: ${f/*\./.} did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is already in the output of find. Any space is considered a separation by the commands following it. You should use the option

```
   -print0
          True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character
          (instead  of  the newline character that -print uses).  This allows file names that
          contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by  pro‐
          grams  that  process  the find output.  This option corresponds to the -0 option of
          xargs.
```

In addition you should use proper apostrophe when using a file name that
could contain a space

```
mv -v "$old" "$ct"
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, no luck.. see the EDIT